# Grouping data in oracle table from 2 diff colums

Tags: sql, oracle, string-aggregation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [comma-separated list as a result of select statement in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324996/comma-separated-list-as-a-result-of-select-statement-in-oracle)

I Have fields like this in a SQL table:

```
ELEMENT_CODE  DIAG_CODE
------------------------
FTD           1234
FTD           1243
FTD           6384
FTD           9938
FLA           9292
FLA           3654
FLA           1122
```

I need records like this in a report in oracle database:

```
ELEMENT_CODE  DIAG_CODE
------------------------
FTD           1234-1243-6374-9938
FLA           9292-3654-1122
```

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)! What *kind* of table? HTML? SQL? Card? What have you tried so far? Help us to help you! Please edit your question; as it stands it cannot be answered and should be closed.

Comment: Its an SQL table, I'm working on oracle 91 database to pull this info and produce it on a report.

Comment: @Pranu. Thanks. ...and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm new to sql, I think i must use group by,set operation, but unable to get an idea how can i avoid repetition of the first name in first colum.

Comment: Giving as much detail as possible is important, because, for example, I know how to do this for SQL Server (using XML PATH) but have no idea how to do it in oracle.

Comment: @MPelletier and @Johnsyweb thanks very much for your support and immediate response.

Answer (score 3):

For Oracle 11g release 2:

```
SELECT ELEMENT_CODE, LISTAGG(DIAG_CODE, '-') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY DIAG_CODE) AS "DIAG_CODES"
FROM SomeTable
GROUP BY ELEMENT_CODE;
```

Pre Oracle 11g release2 would be:

```
SELECT ELEMENT_CODE, WM_CONCAT(DIAG_CODE, '-')
FROM SomeTable
GROUP BY ELEMENT_CODE;
```

Source: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/StringAggregationTechniques.php